# OpenFortiVPN on ARM64 produces errors wheras on AMD64 it works fine

Tags: networking, vpn, arm64

I was using OpenFortiVPN very successfully on my laptop running Ubuntu 22.04.1 to connect to a Fortigate VPN. Recently, after my laptop finally kicked the bucket, I decided to get a Raspberry PI 4 and installed Ubuntu 22.04.1. I am running the exact same config, same network, etc, but on the PI I just cannot initiate a successful connection.

This is the Terminal info I keep getting:

```
INFO:   Connected to gateway.
INFO:   Authenticated.
INFO:   Remote gateway has allocated a VPN.
Couldn't set tty to PPP discipline: Invalid argument
ERROR:  read: Input/output error
INFO:   Cancelling threads...
INFO:   Cleanup, joining threads...
ERROR:  pppd: An immediately fatal error of some kind occurred, such as an essential system call failing, or running out of virtual memory.
INFO:   Terminated pppd.
INFO:   Closed connection to gateway.
INFO:   Logged out.
```

Can someone maybe point me in the right direction?

P.S. I am fairly new to Linux environment.

Comment: @mikewhatever , Thank you kindly for editing my question and correcting the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much Dimitri Papadopoulos Orfanos @ GITHUB for prividing the solution below:

> I doubt it's an ARM64 vs. AMD64 issue. The Raspberry Linux
> distribution lacks a working pppd, probably because of missing kernel
> modules.
>
> Something like this might help:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-raspi
```

It is working perfectly now !!